# Having trouble sorting (list of tuples)

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

I'm trying to do a sort of shop like program, 5 items and it asks you the name of the product and price, i want to organize it by price descending.

```
#initialise variables
product1 = []
product2 = []
product3 = []
product4 = []
product5 = []
products = []
totalCost = 0.0


#input products and prices funtions
def getInput1():
   product1.append(input("What is the product?"))
   product1.append(input("What is the price?"))

def getInput2():
   product2.append(input("What is the product?"))
   product2.append(input("What is the price?"))

def getInput3():
   product3.append(input("What is the product?"))
   product3.append(input("What is the price?"))

def getInput4():
   product4.append(input("What is the product?"))
   product4.append(input("What is the price?"))

def getInput5():
   product5.append(input("What is the product?"))
   product5.append(input("What is the price?"))


#ask user products and prices   
getInput1()
getInput2()
getInput3()
getInput4()
getInput5()

products.append([product1, product2, product3, product4, product5])
products.sort(key=lambda tup: tup[1], reverse = True)

print("List is in format Product Name | Price") 
print(products)
```

it just shows the prices normally and doesnt sort
(p.s) i know it could be tidier but I'm stuck for how

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `products` is a list into which you've inserted *another* list `[product1, product2, product3, product4, product5]`. You're then sorting that outer list (of one element -- the inner list) which of course remains the same.

You could instead do `products = [product1, product2, product3, product4, product5]` in place of `products.append(...)`, and everything should work as you intend.

---

For cleanup, why have all those separate functions? Just write one `get_product` function.

```
def get_product():
    productname = input("What is the product? ")
    productprice = input("What is the price? ")

    return (productname, productprice)
```

Then collect 5 of those:

```
products = []
for _ in range(5):  # this is an idiomatic way to run the code in the for loop 5 times
    product = get_product()
    products.append(product)
```

and sort

```
products.sort(key=lambda t: t[1], reverse=True)
```

Comment: That does help clear up a few things, but i have to sort them by the cost highest to lowest, im not quite sure how to link them together and sort it properly

Comment: @KieranLaing you were doing that part correctly, you just weren't sorting what you thought you were. Instead of sorting a list of products, you were sorting a list that contained one element -- a list of products. Sorting that outer list always gives you the same result (sorting isn't recursive or anything like that): you needed to sort the *inner* list and discard the outer list completely.